# JavaScript input is not being shown correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have a JavaScript program that adds fields according to what the user needs but the input2 is not being showed correctly to user enter with description. Please run the code belo to see.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nome " + (i+1)));
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "Nome etapa" + i;
                input.style.border = "1px solid black";
                container.appendChild(input);

                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Descrição " + (i+1)));
                var input2 = document.createElement("input2");
                input2.type = "text";
                input2.name = "Descrição etapa" + i;
                input2.style.border = "thin dotted red";
                container.appendChild(input2);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there an error in the code or a problem in the browser? or some limitation in number of filds in javascript? How to make the 'Descrição' field apeear?

Any suggestions for what could be the error?

Comment: Where is the closing tag for the div at the end of your HTML? Divs have ending tags.

Comment: I've edited my answer to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a closing `</p>` and `</div>` tags.

They are not self closing tags.

**Edit:**

In response to your edit you need to change the `value=""` in the `<input>` to `value=1`

Change `var input2 = document.createElement("input");`

Comment: Sorry I didnt put the entire html code, but as you can see in the attached image, the imput is not being shown. I have already fixed the problem with the tags not being closed and the error continues. –

Comment: I edited the post. Can you see again? Didn't work with value = 1

Comment: As you can see, the field doesn't appear next to 'Descrição x'. That is the problem. User can put the name, but not description.

Comment: See my edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the code bellow. I changed the document.createElement("input2") to document.createElement("input")

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
            function addFields(){
                // Number of inputs to create
                var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
                // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                // Clear previous contents of the container
                while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
                }
                for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                    // Append a node with a random text
                    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nome " + (i+1)));
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.name = "Nome etapa" + i;
                    input.style.border = "1px solid black";
                    container.appendChild(input);
    
                    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    
                    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Descrição " + (i+1)));
                    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
                    input2.type = "text";
                    input2.name = "Descrição etapa" + i;
                    input2.style.border = "thin dotted red";
                    container.appendChild(input2);
                    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value=2>Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
        <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
        <div id="container"/></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```